# How do I allow protected cells to be edited using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I need to apply protection just on header rows of my spreadsheet but at the same time I also want to enable autofilter

I am able to do both based on the below code, but it also disables cells in the spreadsheet which is empty. For example, in the screenshot I attached, It is not allowing me to edit cell B9

```
df.to_excel(writer_template, sheet_name='inputs')

worksheet = writer_template.sheets['inputs']

unlocked = workbook.add_format({'locked': False})
locked   = workbook.add_format({'locked': True})

worksheet.set_column('B:G', None, unlocked)

# Turn worksheet protection on.
worksheet.protect(options={'autofilter': True})
worksheet.set_row(0, None, locked)
worksheet.set_row(1, None, locked)

worksheet.autofilter('A2:G500')
```

My dataframe looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A good general approach to figuring out how to do something with XlsxWriter is to first figure out how you would do it in Excel.

In Excel all cells have the `locked` property on by default so if you "protect" the sheet then all the cells will be locked for editing. To get around this in Excel you would have to unlock any cells that you wanted allow the user to change.

So in your XlsxWriter example you would have to create an `unlocked` format (like in the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_locked)) and apply that to cells that the user is allowed to edit.

Comment: Actually set_row with unlocked filter worked for me.

Comment: @Shanoo so you found an answer or you are still looking for an answer?